# Load html into div without losing js and css

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to load a html file with it's own stlyesheet and js into a div of another page.

For example the html file i want to load will be something like this

```
<html><head>External syle and js</head><body></body></html>
```

into the `div` tag of other html page using

```
$("#divID").load("htmlpagename.html");
```

When ever I'm loading html it's losing css and I'm thrown with an error in console as

```
GET http://localhost:81/projects/js/table.js?_=1377245019877
jquery.min.js (line 6) 404 Not Found  149ms
```

Comment: Place the ("#divID).load(htmlpagename.html) in quotes, also add $ next to ("#divID).. Lastly, it won't bring the CSS into, just the DOM nodes, thus the HTML structure I believe. Pre-load the CSS file in the same page anyway.

Comment: Is there jQuery included in the other HTML content?

Comment: If your html contains an `html` tag, you might want to use iframe.

Comment: Can you show us a bit more code? And please use the wonderful tools to format it when displaying. Makes life easier.

Comment: Thanks MackieeE, but in actual i have done it like this only        $("div .table").load("html/table.html");

Comment: @Babak Yeah Jquery is included in parent html content

Comment: Can you post your source code? It seems your code is incorrect. Or else if your code is correct you can try using iframe inside your div to load the HTML with its original style and js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to keep the whole content of the page loaded, you'll need to use an `iframe` instead.

Information taken from the `jQuery .load()` documentation:

*jQuery uses the browser's .innerHTML property to parse the retrieved document and insert it into the current document. During this process, browsers often filter elements from the document such as html, title or head elements. As a result, the elements retrieved by .load() may not be exactly the same as if the document were retrieved directly by the browser.*

If you decide to use an `iframe`, this can help you:

```
$("<iframe />").attr("src", "htmlpagename.html").appendTo("#divID");
```

Comment: Thanks for your nice input.

Comment: No problems. Glad to help.

Comment: Nice answer, but why do you changed `.appendTo('#divID');` to `.appendTo($("#divID"));` ?

Comment: Good point. It's pointless. Will edit the answer. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `iframe` in html, so why don't you use `iframe`?

```
<html>
<head>
   <!-- Other Head Files and Tags Here -->
</head>
<body>
    <div id="divID">
        <iframe src="htmlpagename.html"></iframe>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is it not possible to load html into div without losing attached css and js without using iframe?

Comment: @user2710162 Think about what your html will look like if you include directly this html. You will have several `html` tags, which is not valid.

Comment: @user2710162 Yes but then you need to call the css and javascript already with in the head tag, Not Recommended..

Comment: Check my answer. Most browsers will strip off the html, head and even title tags when loading the page content.

Comment: @user2710162 is there any issue with iframe? with respect to your code?

Comment: @user2710162 nice selection of answer and there are no much difference in the approaches but only that my code will create the `iframe` with dom and you don't have to wait for the dom to be loaded completely and then extra time to wait for iframe data to be load into the iframe and any extra overhead for browser to create an iframe after dom load, anyways at least I was the first to suggest the iframe I think, Cheers anyways. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$('<iframe />').attr('src', 'htmlpagename.html').appendTo('#divID');
```

**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bthqu/)**